# subprocess.Popen hangs main application

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pdf, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to follow an example of code that I found [here](https://gist.github.com/hrsano645/a16c3f35deac04b2b4d9) and I've modified the code a bit so it looks like this in my main application

```
def send_to_printer(pdffile):
    acrobat = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'

    # '"%s"'is to wrap double quotes around paths
    # as subprocess will use list2cmdline internally if we pass it a list
    # which escapes double quotes and Adobe Reader doesn't like that

    cmd = '"{}" /N /T "{}" "{}"'.format(acrobat, pdffile, printer_name)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    exit_code = proc.wait()
```

If I run this bit of code all on it's own and hand it the pdf I'm trying to print it works quite well.  It is when I try and call it from my main application that it causes problems.  Basically what I am doing is collecting a bunch of individual pdf's and assembling them together and then printing them so they are double sided.

The code that is calling this looks like this.

```
output1 = PdfFileWriter()
for pdf in args[:len(args)//2]:
    page = PdfFileReader(pdf).getPage(0)
    output1.addPage(page)

outputStream1 = open('front_pages_to_print.pdf', 'wb')
output1.write(outputStream1)
outputStream1.close()

send_to_printer('front_pages_to_print.pdf')
```

When I run the above code before sending it to the printer, it prints the first pages and then hangs.  I've also tried just calling the individual files on their own, but it results in the same behavior. It prints the first page and hangs.  I read up a bit on it and supposedly using proc.wait() can cause a deadlock if you don't use commuicate() as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).  However in the code that I am following it has the line stdout, stderr = proc.communicate() which I am assuming is handling this?  I have to be honest though, I'm trying to understand the code and don't quite get it. Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Edit - This is on windows 10. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

So after fooling around with the debugger it was waiting for

```
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
exit_code = proc.wait()
```

Both of these ended up not receiving a response I guess?  I don't quite understand why but when I took them out it started working.  It could be that adobe opened, and sent the document to the printer and then closed before proc.communicate() could be called.